# How to get tableview cell text label from 2nd viewcontroller to a label from 1st viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, nsnotifications

I'm new iOS developer.
I have 2 viewcontroller like 2 pictures below (I'll called its VC1 and VC2):
VC1:
[image: VC1]

And VC2 is a list of printers:
[image: VC2]

Now I want every time I selected a cell in VC2 then press right bar button in top right the text label of cell will send to VC1 and display instead of **EP-806A**
label, I've searched on internet and found solution is write a delegate to passing data. But I don't know how to write it in my case. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I think no need for delegate here, just write one singleton class which can stored your data when you selected any cell and access that data in another view.

Comment: @PravinTate: you mean I can store it into NSUserdefault instead of using delegate, right?

Comment: No, don't use NSUserdefault just make one single class as singleton and stored data in that.
just search what is mean by singleton class and how to use it. 
so you will get all idea about how to solve your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st In VC2, you must create delegate

```
@protocol VC2Delegate;
@interface VC2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <VC2Delegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol VC2Delegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)changeToText:(NSString *)text;
@end

@implementation VC2
// this is your "完了" action
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {
   ...
   [self.delegate changeToText:@"what you want"];
}
@end
```

2nd, add the delegate to VC1

```
@interface VC1 : UIViewController <VC2Delegate>
@end
```

3rd, remember set VC2.delegate to VC1

```
VC2 *vc2 = [VC2 new];
vc2.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

4th, implement `changeToText:` in VC1

```
@implementation VC1
- (void)changeToText:(NSString *)text {
    // change the text here
}
@end
```

wish it could help you.